# How do I get my program to read the length of a word?

Tags: python, function, tuples

```
#Task 10.3
passw = tuple()
#empty tuple


passw = input("Create a password: ")
#adds a password into the passw tuple

if passw < str(len(6)):
    print("Your password is too short")
else:
    print("Your password has been changed")
```

Should be a simple piece of code. Logically, I think it should look like this, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: `if len(passw) < 6`…?!

Comment: `passw = tuple()` is entirely superfluous. The next line doesn't *add* to the tuple, it simply replaces it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the `len` function to `passw`:

```
if len(passw) < 6:
    print("Your password is too short")
else:
    print("Your password has been changed")
```

It's also worth noting that `passw = input("Create a password: ")` does not in fact add the password "into the passw tuple" - it just overwrites the tuple with the string value produced by `input()`.

You might want to use `getpass` instead of `input`:

```
#Task 10.3
from getpass import getpass

# reads password from user into the passw variable
passw = getpass("Create a password: ")

if len(passw) < 6:
    print("Your password is too short")
else:
    print("Your password has been changed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this! `if 6 > len(passw):`

Answer (score 0):

The return value from *input()* is a string. You can determine the length of the string with the *len()* function

```
passw = input('Create a password: ')

if len(passw) >= 6:
    print('Your password has been changed')
else:
    print('Your password is too short')
```